# How do I create a .sql file in ubuntu server?

Tags: php, file, ubuntu, server, creation

I actually have this create.php code

```
<?php 
    //ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
    $mysqlUserName      = "root";
    $mysqlPassword      = "admin";
    $mysqlHostName      = "localhost";
    $DbName             = "corporativostr_inventario";
    $backup_name        = "corporativostr_inventario.sql";
    $tables             = array("articulos","articulos_eliminados","categorias","conceptos","proveedores","registros","responsables","responsables_eliminados","usuarios","usuarios_eliminados");

   //or add 5th parameter(array) of specific tables:    array("mytable1","mytable2","mytable3") for multiple tables

    Export_Database($mysqlHostName,$mysqlUserName,$mysqlPassword,$DbName,  $tables=false, $backup_name=false );

    function Export_Database($host,$user,$pass,$name,  $tables=false, $backup_name=false )
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$name); 
        $mysqli->select_db($name); 
        $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

        $queryTables    = $mysqli->query('SHOW TABLES'); 
        while($row = $queryTables->fetch_row()) 
        { 
            $target_tables[] = $row[0]; 
        }   
        if($tables !== false) 
        { 
            $target_tables = array_intersect( $target_tables, $tables); 
        }
        foreach($target_tables as $table)
        {
            $result         =   $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);  
            $fields_amount  =   $result->field_count;  
            $rows_num=$mysqli->affected_rows;     
            $res            =   $mysqli->query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table); 
            $TableMLine     =   $res->fetch_row();
            $content        = (!isset($content) ?  '' : $content) . "\n\n".$TableMLine[1].";\n\n";

            for ($i = 0, $st_counter = 0; $i < $fields_amount;   $i++, $st_counter=0) 
            {
                while($row = $result->fetch_row())  
                { //when started (and every after 100 command cycle):
                    if ($st_counter%100 == 0 || $st_counter == 0 )  
                    {
                            $content .= "\nINSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES";
                    }
                    $content .= "\n(";
                    for($j=0; $j<$fields_amount; $j++)  
                    { 
                        $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n", addslashes($row[$j]) ); 
                        if (isset($row[$j]))
                        {
                            $content .= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; 
                        }
                        else 
                        {   
                            $content .= '""';
                        }     
                        if ($j<($fields_amount-1))
                        {
                                $content.= ',';
                        }      
                    }
                    $content .=")";
                    //every after 100 command cycle [or at last line] ....p.s. but should be inserted 1 cycle eariler
                    if ( (($st_counter+1)%100==0 && $st_counter!=0) || $st_counter+1==$rows_num) 
                    {   
                        $content .= ";";
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $content .= ",";
                    } 
                    $st_counter=$st_counter+1;
                }
            } $content .="\n\n\n";
        }
        //$backup_name = $backup_name ? $backup_name : $name."___(".date('H-i-s')."_".date('d-m-Y').")__rand".rand(1,11111111).".sql";
        $backup_name = $backup_name ? $backup_name : $name.".sql";
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');   
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$backup_name."\"");  
        echo $content; exit;
    }
?>
```

which creates a downloadable .sql file when I open the .php file in other PC with the web navigator

But when I run it with in ubuntu server I only see the db content.

How can I create a .sql file in the same directory where the create.php is located?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create the .sql file with this code, this code is creating database with name `prueba`

In order to create a .sql file file we use command line queries (can be used using application level too).

```
mysqldump -u'user' -p'password' database_name > /path/filename.sql
```

This will create a `.sql` file and you can use the same query on the application level to create the database .sql provided the database use has the proper rights.

you can use other parameters like --routines in case your database has subroutines. There are a number of optional parameters.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. I alrady edited it. Is it possible to use mysqldump to export a db from an internet server?